# error: 2147217900(80040e14) in Ms access VBA code

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am using a piece of pre-written code in a MS Access db as I have very minimal knowledge of VBA.

This is the snippet:

```
If tbl.Name = "TEMP_LOAD" Then
            Set rs1 = New ADODB.Recordset
            rs1.Open "SELECT " & tbl.Name & ".[SPECIFICATION], CLng([" & tbl.Name & "]![SORT_SEQ]) AS SORT_SEQ, CLng([" & tbl.Name & "]![SORT]) AS SORT, CLng([" & tbl.Name & "]![SEQ]) AS SEQ, " & tbl.Name & ".[CLASS], " & tbl.Name & ".[CHAR], " & tbl.Name & ".[VALUE], " & tbl.Name & ".[VALIDITY_AREA], " & tbl.Name & ".[BUS_ID], " & tbl.Name & ".[TEXT_CAT], " & tbl.Name & ".[TEXT], " & tbl.Name & ".[DOKNR], " & tbl.Name & ".[ORD] FROM " & tbl.Name & " INNER JOIN CFG_Data_Providers ON " & tbl.Name & ".[CLASS] = CFG_Data_Providers.[Class] WHERE (((CFG_Data_Providers.[Data_Provider])='" & data_origin & "')) ORDER BY TEMP_LOAD.Total, " & tbl.Name & ".[SPECIFICATION], CLng([" & tbl.Name & "]![SORT_SEQ]), CLng([" & tbl.Name & "]![SORT]), CLng([" & tbl.Name & "]![SEQ]), " & tbl.Name & ".[ORD];", Application.CurrentProject.Connection
```

When the code runs I am getting `Error: 2147217900(80040e14)` stating `Invalid Use Of Nulls` in the last line. I am using 32 bit access db on windows 10.

Does anyone know what the reason and fix for this error is?

Comment: As you'll probably only get the error on the CLng() function , I would suspect that one of those fields is Null in your underlying data? Possible solution would be to use the NZ() function inside the field value to return 0 beforehand, ? CLng(Nz([YourFieldName],0))

Comment: @Minty Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, you have a *Null* value in one or more fields, and that will fail - for `CLng(Null)`.

You should be able to use *Int* instead, like:

```
Int([" & tbl.Name & "]![SORT_SEQ])
```

or, if a returned *Null* is not acceptable, use *Nz*:

```
CLng(Nz([" & tbl.Name & "]![SORT_SEQ],0))
```